# Looping over two variables in tandem (ie. over pairs) in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of files in ids1. Example

```
s1_aaa
s1_aab
s1_aac
```

I want to submit jobs for these files using sbatch: I use

```
for x in `cat ids1`;do sbatch batch_job.sbatch $x ;done
```

This works fine.

Now I try for 2 variables in the for loop. Example I have another file ids2 like

```
s2_aaa
s2_aab
s2_aac
```

I want to submit jobs for files in `ids1` and `ids2` simultaneously i.e. pairs (s1_aaa,s2_aaa), (s1_aab,s2_aab), (s1_aac,s2_aac) and so on. When I try

```
for x,y in `cat ids1;cat ids2`;do sbatch batchjob.sbatch $x $y ;done
```

I get the error

```
-bash: `x,y': not a valid identifier
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bash doesn't support multiple variables per for-in loop.

Comment: btw, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001; `for` loops are the wrong tool to use for line-by-line iteration in general.

Answer (score 2):

Read each into an array:

```
# in bash 4.0 or newer
readarray -t ids1 <ids1 # read each line from file ids1 into array ids1
readarray -t ids2 <ids2 # read each line from file ids2 into array ids2
```

...or, in bash 3.x:

```
ids1=( ); ids2=( )
while IFS= read -r id; do ids1+=( "$id" ); done <ids1
while IFS= read -r id; do ids2+=( "$id" ); done <ids2
```

...and iterate over indexes:

```
for idx in "${!ids1[@]}"; do # iterate over indexes in ids1
  id1=${ids1[$idx]} # and use that index to look up items in *both* arrays
  id2=${ids2[$idx]}
  echo "Processing $id1 and $id2"
done
```

---

Another option is to use `paste` to combine both files into a single stream, and use a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to iterate over the two combined columns:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r id1 id2; do
  echo "Processing $id1 and $id2"
done < <(paste ids1 ids2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the lines match in the two files, you can paste them first and iterate on them pairwise, i.e.,

```
while read a b; do sbatch batchjob.sbatch $a $b; done < <(paste ids1 ids2)
```

Comment: Believe I beat you there (albeit in an edit that got folded into my other edits, so it's hard to see the timeline).

Comment: perhaps, yours is more comprehensive and longer to write, even if not commit time you beat in answer time for sure.